# ranger: open many files with mplayer

Tags: mplayer, file-manager, file-opening, ranger

I use the file explorer called ranger and I wonder if it is possible to open many files in different directory with mplayer?

What I can already do is to select all the files (pressing <kbd>v</kbd>) from one directory and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Mplayer is launched and all the files in that directory are played one after the other.

But what if I want to play a list of files that are in different directories?

EDIT: To be more general, I'd like to know how to run a command that takes files from different directories as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my solution for playing all files in a directory and all subdirectories with `mplayer2` and `ranger` in random order.** It's is not exactly the answer to the question, but maybe you can expand it.

First I wrote a shell script called `ptv`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
  echo "usage: $(basename $0) directory [count]"
else
  if [[ ! -z "$2" ]]; then
    SHUFPARAM="-n$2"
  fi
  PLAYLIST="/tmp/playlist-$(whoami)"
  CWD="$(realpath "$1")"
  find "$CWD" -type f -iname \*.mkv -or -iname \*.mp4 -or -iname \*.avi | shuf $SHUFPARAM > $PLAYLIST && \
    mplayer2 --playlist=$PLAYLIST && rm -f $PLAYLIST
fi
```

This script finds all my movie files in a given directory, creates a random ordered playlist and calls `mplayer2` with this generated playlist. Leave the `shuf` command out, if you want a sorted list.

Next step is to edit `rifle.conf` in your settings directory (`~/.config/ranger`). Add this line:

```
directory, label pseudoTV, has mplayer2, flag f = /path/to/ptv "$@"
```

Now you can use the script to `open_with` (mapped to key: `r`) with `mplayer2`. In `mplayer2` you can navigate with `<` and `>` between the playlist items.

*TIP: Copy your directories directories to the `yank_buffer` and save it in `ranger`. Then expand `ptv` to find files in all your selected directories...*

Answer (score 3):

Answer from: http://ranger.carina.uberspace.de/qa/358/open-several-marked-files.
I tested this and it works.

Marking is limited to 1 directory. To open files in multiple directories, you need to use the copy buffer instead:

1. Move to a file you want to use and type "ya" to add the file to the copy buffer. If you mark files with space or v, they will all be added at the same time.
2. Type:

   :shell command %c

   To use all the files with the given command. %c is expanded to all the  files of the copy buffer.
3. Finally type "uy" to reset the copy buffer.

Comment: thanks, that works but it's quite unpractical...

Comment: @PinkFloyd maybe because your demand is unpractical or you should use smplayer which has gui

Answer (score 2):

You should use `smplayer` (the best GUI for `mplayer`, which supports all the features `mplayer` has) instead of `mplayer` (which is a command line tool).

If your open command for audio files looks like this

```
smplayer -add-to-playlist
```

the selected files will be added to smplayer’s internal playlist. You can easily select and add files from different directories to be played.

Answer (score 0):

You better use a [command line interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) to launch mplayer, in Linux it is [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29), look at my command:

```
~bash~ $ mplayer 1st_screen/JacksonSisters-IBelieveInMiracles.mp3 \
> 2nd_screen/\(15\)\ Memory\ Gospel\ -\ Moby.flac \
> 3rd_screen/01\ -\ Iggy\ Pop\ -\ Livin\'\ on\ the\ Edge\ of\ the\ Night.flac \
> 4th_screen/05\ -\ We\ Must\ Believe\ In\ Magic.flac
```

Where 1st_screen, 2nd_screen, 3rd_screen, 4th_screen is a different directories.

You can always launch two instance of mplayer at one moment in different shells, two songs will make noise simultaneously.

Comment: i knew that command but thx. this command is not practical when you want to open a lot of files because you need to write them all (or use a `*` if you want to select many files). ranger provides a way to select files with `v` or `space` that is very useful.